# Laravel post request doesn't return correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

My form is not updating the information when I manually change the textbox fields. When i get a confirmation email I get the wrong calculation in this example. When i process the information in my controllers it gets put correct in the database but incorrect in the email to my customer. even though it uses the same information.

```
$('#two-inputs').dateRangePicker(
    {
        separator : ' tot ',
        startDate: '{{$start_date->start_date}}',
        endDate: '{{$end_date->end_date}}',
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ disabled.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
        },
        getValue: function()
        {
            if ($('#date-range200').val() && $('#date-range201').val() )
                return $('#date-range200').val() + ' to ' + $('#date-range201').val();
            else
                return '';
        },
        setValue: function(s,s1,s2)
        {
            var total = 0;
            var temp_s1 = s1.split("-");
            var temp_s2 = s2.split("-");
            $('#date-range200').val(temp_s1[2] + "-" + temp_s1[1] + "-" + temp_s1[0]);
            $('#date-range201').val(temp_s2[2] + "-" + temp_s2[1] + "-" + temp_s2[0]);
            var start_date = s1;
            var s1 = s1.split('-');
            var s1 = new Date(s1[0], s1[1] - 1, s1[2]);
            var s2 = s2.split('-');
            var s2 = new Date(s2[0], s2[1] - 1, s2[2]);
            //alert(datediff(s1, s2));
            if(obj[$('#date-range200').val()] == null){
                var prijs = {{$highest_price->name}};
            } else {
                var prijs = obj[$('#date-range200').val()];
            }

            var extra_kosten = {{$blog->schoonmaak}};
            total += extra_kosten;
            total += datediff(s1, s2)*prijs;

            $("#aantal_nachten").val(datediff(s1, s2));
            $("#prijs_per_nacht").val(prijs);
            $("#totaal_prijs_nachten").val(total);
            $("#prijs").html(prijs);
            $("#nachten").html(datediff(s1, s2));
            $("#prijs_nachten").html(datediff(s1, s2)*prijs);
            $("#extra_kosten").html(extra_kosten);
            $("#totaal_prijs").html(total);
            //alert(start_date);
            //alert(obj[$('#date-range200').val()]);
            $("#prijstable").slideDown( "slow");

        }
    });
```

Screenshot of the input fields
[image: This is the form inputs i used for this item.]

Screenshot of what i get in the email i receive
[image]

Screenshot of how it shows in my database
[image]

Comment: Please explain what values you get as opposed to what values you expect. Just saying that you get "wrong values" does not help.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i added some more screenshots

Comment: Please don't use Dutch in your code

Comment: You can use Dates mutators https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.. The information in the mail are incorrect but correct in your DB. Do you build the email with Javascript ?

Comment: Yes, i really want to know from where you are triggering your email ( provide code if possible ) from controller using mailable ? because i think you're not parsing correct info in your mail function otherwise while getting data from get or post in controller saving correct information.

Comment: if you meant with format of date displaying on email then {{ date("d/m/Y",$mydate) }}